# How to install koalixcrm docker on synology DS918+, How to run docker compose on synology

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, synology

I purchased a Synology DS918+ because I would like to install and run the docker file of koalixcrm https://github.com/scaphilo/koalixcrm. (This is a django based crm which requires postgresql docker as well

Through the GUI i can only upload a docker file and install it but I need to run docker compose to set up the full application with the database.

Does anyone known how to do this on the Synology?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a few steps more to install koalixcrm on a Synology Disk Station. As far as I can see, Synology really does not support the execution of docker-compose via Docker manager, but you are able to execute docker commands directly on your Disk Station by using SSH connection.

1. Make sure, you have activated SSH for your Disk Station

   - Open DSM --> System Control --> Terminal & SNMP
   - In Terminal activate SSH and save your changes
2. Copy the docker-compose.prod file from the koalixCRM project to your Disk Station (E.g. with drag and drop functionality to File Station --> docker)
3. Now you have to connect over SSH to your Disk Station

   - Download putty (https://www.putty.org/), install and open it.
   - Configure connection and click Open button

     - Host Name: the ip of your Disk Station
     - Port: 22
     - Connection type: SSH
   - Login with your Disk Station user and password
4. Navigate to your docker directory: `cd volume1/docker`
5. Execute docker-compose.prod.yml: `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up`
6. Check if the two new containers (postgres and koalixcrm) are up and running.